# Stop zmq message

Tags: c++, message, zeromq, send

When I use `send` and the addressee is not listening, `zmq` internally will keep trying until the message is delivered. Are there any way to stop this? For example, try for 5 seconds and stop? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `zmq_setsockopt` and set the `ZMQ_LINGER` option (that is the timeout for subsequent operations).

`send` can also use `ZMQ_NOBLOCK` to return immediately, but then subsequent `close` will still block, so the `ZMQ_LINGER` option is preferred.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do this and it worked for me! I used both, thanks.